# Add external date column in tableau

Tags: function, date, tableau-api

How to add external date columns in tableau
I have 2  date columns like check in and check out but i want data on current date not depend on that both dates
Like u have to find out occupancy of 3 days (yesterday, Today and tomorrow)not on check-in or not on checkout date

Comment: use: TODAY() https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm

Comment: I already did  this for today's data,But I want also next day and last day data (individually) not only for today.

Comment: You can do that with date functions. Review those functions in the link provided above (DATEDIFF, DATEADD, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tableau]

```
Use the Date functions -

`Today` - Today()
`Tomorrow` - DATEADD('day',1,[Today])
`Yesterday`-DATEADD('day',-1,[Today])
```